# Integration test for Java ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an application which takes uses ExecutorService, to creates multiple threads & execute certain operation asynchronously.

```
for (final Product product : products) {
    executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateFewAttributes(product);
        }
    });
}
```

I am trying to write an integration test to verify, whether the operation has been performed correctly.
Since the operation is asynchronous, finding it difficult to assert the expected attributes.

Tried to do awaitTermination before asserting, but this doesn't seem to work.

```
executorService.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: I think you have to call `shutdown` before `awaitTermination`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using your own implementation (or a mock) of `ExecutorService`, which will not use threads, but rather mimic thread like behavior (or it can used threads but in a controlled manner). This way you'll have as much control as needed.

This of course depends on the code being tested being testable enough to use a different `ExecutorService` for tests than for production, i.e. either the `ExecutorService` instance is being passed to it, or injected into it.

Comment: This is supposed to be an "integration" test, though.

Comment: That's not a problem. The only thing you're "mocking"/"faking" is the executor service, which (as far as I understand from your question) a is standard implementation. In other words, your test is executing your production code as usual, but instead of using an external API that you can't control, it uses a fake one, which you can control. This doesn't change the fact that the code being tested (your code) is the real thing.

Comment: I don't know... If you fake the executor service to the point where your code is no longer being run concurrently/asynchronously, you might be missing subtle problems in thread-safety (of course, depending on how subtle those are, you won't be catching them anyway with a moderate amount of testing).

Comment: I don't suggest you give up on asynchronous or concurrent operation, I'm just saying that if you have your own `ExecutorService` implementation intended solely for testing, you can create it so that controlling the termination of threads, etc. are easy, unlike when you're using the real implementation that will be in production. That's what I would do, anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

The [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) generates a [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) that you can use to await for the computation to finish. According to [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) documentation:

> Method submit extends base method Executor.execute(java.lang.Runnable) by creating and returning a Future that can be used to cancel execution and/or wait for completion.

Storing the [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)s your `executorService.submit` method call returns and then calling [`Future#get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) on all of your futures will ensure your `Runnable` will finish executing. According to [`Future#get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) documentation:

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

It should be safe to make your assertions after that.